# How to call a function from another Controller?

Tags: javascript, function

I am making an app to calculate some budget so i have 3 controller. The second controller is called UIConntroller and its work is to get input from the user and return to the last controller called 'controller'. Then, from this last controller, I call the get inputInput function inside the UIConntroller. When I try to call this function I get an error that the UICtrl.getInput is not a function.

My target is to call the functions in the UIConntroller.

```
var budgetController = (function () {

} )();


//===========BDGET CONTROLER========== this gets input from the user
var UIConntroller = (function () {
     return {
         getInput: function () {
             return {
             type : document.querySelector('.add__type').value, //will be eithe inc or exp
            description : document.querySelector('.add__description').value,
             value : document.querySelector('.add__value').value
             };
         }
     };
});


//=========GLOBAL APP CONTROLLER========================================
var controller =(function (budgetCtrl,UICtrl) {

    var ctrlAddItem = function () {
            // 1.Get te input field data
            var input = UICtrl.getInput();
            console.log(input);


            //2. Add the item to the budget controller


            //3. Add The Items to the UI


            //4. Calculate the budget 


            //5. Display the budget to the UI


    }

    document.querySelector('.add__btn').addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);
//key press event listiner
    document.addEventListener('keypress',function(event){
        if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which ===13) {
            ctrlAddItem();
        } else {

        }

    })

})(budgetController,UIConntroller);
```

When I run the code I expect the getInput function below to be called so that it can take input from the user:

```
getInput: function () {
             return {
             type : document.querySelector('.add__type').value, //will be eithe inc or exp
            description : document.querySelector('.add__description').value,
             value : document.querySelector('.add__value').value
             };
         }
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Looks fine (kind of). What's the error/output? Btw: You sometimes spell "controller" wrong.

Comment: Actually, I think you forgot to call the self-executed function for `UIConntroller`. You're missing `()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IIFE for `UIConntroller` is missing `()` to invoke it

```
//===========BDGET CONTROLER========== this gets input from the user
var UIConntroller = (function () {
     return {
         getInput: function () {
             return {
             type : document.querySelector('.add__type').value, //will be eithe inc or exp
            description : document.querySelector('.add__description').value,
             value : document.querySelector('.add__value').value
             };
         }
     };
}());
//^^^ Missing ()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
UICtrl().getInput();
```